# Does FB auto generate new token after exist one expire?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use Facebook SDK to login user for my app and on FaceBook API page it says

> Mobile apps that use Facebook's iOS and Android SDKs get long-lived tokens by default... long-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about 60 days

Let say a user logins to my app with Facebook, I then create a unique ID for that user and stores it in Userdefaults. If the user clicks logout, I will remove that unique id from UserDefaults and logout the user from facebook SDK.

My question here is what if the user exit my app without logout and then comeback after 61 days. Will facebook auto generate new token for that user? and of course the user status is still login in my app because the unique ID hasn't been removed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Facebook SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing)

When you use iOS, Android, or our JavaScript SDK, the SDK will handle making sure that tokens are refreshed before they expire during this 90-day period. Native mobile apps using Facebook's SDKs get long-lived access tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens will be refreshed once per day, for up to 90 days, when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers. If no requests are made, the token will expire after about 60 days and the person will have to go through the login flow again to get a new token.

So yes, in your case the user needs to go through login flow again.

You can use [login status api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#10--check-login-status) to validate token every time the user enters the app.

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken == null;
boolean isExpired = accessToken.isExpired();
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: @Vaibhav Kumar, How about refreshing access token for pages without using the `login flow`. I just need to refresh the token from an android app without user intervention and without going to the `Token Tool` and extend my token, how do I do that?